# Why tirupathi's doors are not allowed to be widened?

Tags: dharma-shastras, tirupati

As I was watching series about Tirupati Tirumala Documentary on National Geographic, as per them they are following some aadama shastra and as per that even if they want they won't be allowed to widened or make bigger gates of the temple entrance. Why is that so ?